# How to make a link redirect for my c# app

Tags: c#, networking, hyperlink

so ive seen stuff like stuff://filepath where it downloads something how can i add that for my program? I want too download this `https://modelsaber.com/files/saber/1584894113/Doriru_CC.saber` and put it in a path relative too my .exe im using a .net framework 4.8 forms app
I also have no networking experience :/

EDIT: i forgot too mention the link i need too download from is `modelsaber://saber/1584894113/Doriru_CC.saber`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to download the file in a relative path beside your .exe file

```
    public Main()
    {
        string url = "https://modelsaber.com/files/saber/1584894113/Doriru_CC.saber";
        SaveUrl(url,"relativePath");           
    }

    private async void SaveUrl(string url,string relativePath)
    {
        string targetPath = Path.Combine(".", relativePath);
        if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
        }
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadFile(url,Path.Combine(targetPath, Path.GetFileName(url)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: how can i make it download from `modelsaber://saber/1584894113/Doriru_CC.saber` ?

Comment: Please clarify your question.